# What's the best way to swap words?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm familiar with `ddp` to swap lines, but what if I want to swap words on the same line? I found a Reddit post that linked to this [wiki page](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines) that suggests `dawbP` as a word swap method, but this seems long-winded for a Vim keypress series. Is there a shorter method to execute this?

For reference, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
One Two Three Four
```

-->

```
One Three Two Four
```

Answer (score 2):

With your cursor between One and Two (in normal mode), type `deep`.

Answer (score 1):

From the wiki page, I've always used the other methods that leave the spaces the way they are.

Since that time, my mappings have evolved into something like two 30-lines long functions: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/vim-tip-swap-word.vim

Anyway, a 5 keys sequence isn't long. Moreover you can always define a mapping to shorten the sequence. I'm using `gw` and `gW`.